# Why does pygame.sndarray.make_sound seemingly quadruple the sound duration?

Tags: python, numpy, pygame, audio

The following code:

```
import pygame, numpy
pygame.mixer.pre_init(frequency=96000,size=-16,channels=1)
pygame.init()
a = numpy.random.randn(96000)
sound = pygame.sndarray.make_sound(a)
print sound.get_length()
```

yields a print-out of 4.0, suggesting that the specified duration of 96000 samples at a 96000kHz sampling rate was somehow quadrupled somewhere along the way. Any idea what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data going into make_sound isn't 16 bit integers, (as your pre_init() suggests they should be).  Before calling make_sound() try...

```
a = a.astype(numpy.int16)
```

You might want to also make sure that you use a method of generating your random numbers that causes them to fall into the range of 16 bit ints. Values in the array should be between -32768 to 32767 (with those bounds representing maximum volume).